# How to check for the same word in a string?

Tags: java, string

My code takes a String input, separates them and locates the ones with a specific letter in them, then prints them. Now, i want to make sure the same word only prints once. For instance, if the input was " she looks nice, she is kind." then the output would be "she \n nice" This is my current code:

```
    Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = kybd.nextLine();
String[] arr = s.split(" ");    
for ( String ss : arr) {
    String []ary = {ss};
        for(int i = 0; i < ary.length; i++){
            int numindex = ss.indexOf("e");
            int numindex2 = ss.indexOf("E");
            if (numindex != -1){
                System.out.println(ary[i]);
            }
            else if(numindex2 != -1){
                System.out.println(ary[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions on how to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Add your words to a `HashSet<String>`.

Then loop through this HashSet and print out the words.
Even if there are duplicates (while you extract them),
they will be printed out once.

The HashSet will get rid of the duplicates for you
(it will do that while you insert them into the HashSet).

See here for details: [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

Comment: To maintain word-in-sentence order, an ArrayList (for storage) and a HashSet (for testing previous existence) can be used; if there is no efficiency concern (which there is likely not for small lists as here), then List.contains will be sufficient for the existence test (and the Set can be skipped) .. and be much easier than manual arrays.

Comment: No, to maintain order I would use a TreeSet. At least in this scenario. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

Comment: Oh, OK. I misunderstood your point, maybe you should mention you mean insertion order in your comment. Right, OK.

Comment: I added clarification to the original comment .. but an ArrayList isn't even needed if printing directly. I think this answer could expand on that (as my comment did not): that is, the testing can be moved to a test *on* insert (and the word printed or not as appropriate), instead of simply looking at the Set after every word has been added. Anyway, a Set if a very useful structure in this case.